# Javascript: Display clickable images at the end of each paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function createPopup(event){
        $('<div class="popup"><img src="mysrc.jpg" img style="opacity=0.5; width:50px; height:50px;"></img></div>').appendTo('body');
        positionPopup(event); 
    };  
    function positionPopup(event){
        var tPosX = 950;
        var tPosY = event.clientY+25;
        $('div.popup').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': tPosY, 'left':tPosX});
        $('#test').attr('ydown', parseInt(tPosY)+ parseInt(add));
    };
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('cposs');
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        var imagetest = document.createElement("img");
        imagetest.src = "mysrc.jpg";
        elements[i].onmouseover = function(){
        this.style.background = 'Green';
        createPopup(event);
        }
        elements[i].onmouseout = function(){
        this.style.background = '';
        }
        var ycoor= $('#test').attr('ydown');
        $( "#test" ).append( "<a href=http://www.google.com><img src='mysrc.jpg'</img></a>" );
    }
});
</script>

    <div id="test" ydown="<?php echo $ydown; ?>" xdown="<?php echo $xdown; ?>">
```

There is then multiple paragraphs with `<cposs></cposs>` tags and this allows the text to be highlighted when the mouse is hovered over and creates a popup image to the right of the paragraph. I also have for each counted `<cposs></cposs>` an image that is displayed in the test div.

There is a couple things I was hoping I would be able to accomplish:

- On page load, I would like an image to be displayed at the end of each `<cposs></cposs>` text. Instead of fixed coordinates.
- I would like these images to execute a function when clicked on.(Tried adding the "onclick" attribute but said the function was not defined)
- Eventually, I would like the clickable images to cause the text between the cposs tags to highlight. Similar to what I have now, but instead of mouse over, its a click event.

EDIT:
I have tried to add an onclick attribute to the appended image but once the image is clicked, says the function is not defined.
I am unsure on how to get the coordinates of the cposs tags. I am confused on if I am able to use offset and or position function in javascript. I have attempted to use both and have not succeeded. 
I guess all I really need to know if how to get the end coordinates of the cposs tags and how to give each displayed image a clickable function

I am a big fan of jsfiddle!
Any sort of help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for asking "what is wrong with what I have".  It is **not** for requesting working code.  Give it a go, show us what you have, what you're struggling to get working... but don't ask us to do things for you

Comment: I have attempted to do these tasks multiple of times.
I will edit my post to show what I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/sn625r3z/14/

To make freshly added elements clickable you should be using jQuery's ".on" function and pass an event to it. Something like this:

```
$('img.new-image').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().css({background: 'green'});    
});
```

In the jsFiddle example I positioned images with CSS. But if you want to get the  coordinates to position the image at the end of the block I would do it like this:

```
$('cposs').each(function(){
   var el = $(this);
   var width = el.width();
   var height = el.height();

   var newElement = $('<img class="new-image" src="'+imagetest.src+'" />');
   el.append(newElement);
   newElement.css({top: height+"px", left: width+"px"});
});
```

Hope this helps.